# how to represent some kind of matrix data tables in django models?

Tags: django, forms, models

Need some help really,

How to represent a kind of data like the one below, using django models?
, so that I can build forms to add/edit/delete entries, and build some reporting efficiently?

This is for illustrative purpose, a table of numbers of disease occurences on each month of year, based on disease types, age_group of patient which further divided into male and female, and then into recurring and new occurences.

occurence entries on parent group would be aggregates of its children.

```
year : 2014 month : January
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                |   age_group1    |   age_group2   |  etc .. 
                                | male   | female |male   | female |           
                                | rec|new|rec|new |rec|new|rec|new |                                
----------------------------------------------------------------------
infectious disease group        : 11   5   
    viral disease subgroup      :  8   0                             etc ...
       viral_disease1           :  4   0
       viral disease2           :  4   0
    bacterial disease subgroup  :  3   5
       bacter_disease1          :  1   4
       bacter_disease2          :  2   1
degenerative disease group      :
    neural_disease subgroup     :
        neur_disease1           :
        neur_disease2           :
     ... etc ..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one design you could work with. It allows for flexibility with defining the diseases as well as the reports. If you wanted, you could create a new `Report` model with the start and end fields on that and a ManyToMany to the `DiseaseReport` model. This design assumes you've given the data in bulk. If you're given the individual patient information, then this will have to be modified.

```
class AgeGroup(models.Model):
    pass

class PatientGroup(models.Model):
    NEW = 0
    RECURRING = 1
    PATIENT_STATES = (
        (NEW, "New"),
        (RECURRING, "Recurring"),
    )
    age_group = models.ForeignKey(AgeGroup)
    is_male = models.BooleanField()
    state = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=PATIENT_STATES, default=NEW)

DiseaseGroup(models.Model):
    parent_disease = models.ForeignKey(DiseaseGroup, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

Disease(models.Model):
    disease_group = models.ForeignKey(DiseaseGroup)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

DiseaseReport(models.Model):
    start = models.DateField()
    end = models.DateField()
    disease = models.ForeignKey(Disease)
    patient_group = models.ForeignKey(PatientGroup)
    cases = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: DiseaseGroup model using self recursive foreign key?

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I thought of. You can make a Closure Table if you'd like. Here's a little write up on it. https://coderwall.com/p/lixing